# Rails 3.2 Gemified Engines: Reaching modules inside a mounted gemified engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-engines

I'm working on an infrastructure for Rails application and I'm trying to take something out of someones existing project.
I am sort of new to rails but I read the guides on plugins and engines ect..

So I have a gemified Engine, containing some module. I have a model say SharedPost trying to extend said module and I'm getting the uninitialized constant error

```
uninitialized constant Stake::SharedPost
```

Here's some of what my engine looks like:

```
#file: lib/stake/shared_post.rb
module Stake
  module SharedPost
    ...
  end
end

#file: lib/stake/engine.rb    
module Stake
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Stake

  end
end
```

And in the main app I've got

```
#file: Gemfile
...
gem 'stake'
...

#file: config/routes.rb
Pop::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'home#index'

  mount Stake::Engine, :at => '/stake'
end

#file: app/models/posted.rb
class Posted < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Stake::SharedPost
    ...
  end
end
```

The main application will load, though with no available data on it.
While I try to run

```
rake db:seed
```

for example when trying to load the Posted model I get the error `uninitialized constant Stake::SharedPost`

What am I missing to get access to my gem's namespaced modules?

EDIT:
I've read into the acts_as pattern and that doesn't seem to be the cleanest way of doing things, plus I'm not sure how to implement that onto my engine. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `lib/stake.rb` are you including the `lib/stake/shared_post.rb` file?

It should look something like this:

```
# file lib/stake.rb

require "stake/shared_post.rb"

module stake
    ....
end
```

Comment: I actually figured this out a while after posting but thought the post was long gone for some reason. Thanks! A question though, how come files in the lib directory don't get required automatically? isn't that something rails and\or the Gemfile are supposed to do?

Comment: As far as I know, files in the lib directory do get required automatically - just perhaps not in nested folders. Also, the behavior of an isolated namespaced engine is probably a little different than a normal rails application? Also if just all files were automatically required, then they would all be accessible from the main app - and you might not want to expose all of them.  Sorry these are all just guesses :) It's not something I've looked into extensively, but hope that helps!